# toLowerCase or capitalize functions for Sublime Text 2 Snippets

Tags: ide, sublimetext2

Is it possible to define some sort of `capitalize()` or `toLowerCase()` function when creating Sublime Text 2 Snippets?

For example:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<?php
class ${1} extends Datamapper
{
    var \$has_one = array();
    var \$has_many = array();
    var \$table = '${1}s';
    //constructor and other stuff next...
}
?>
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>dmm</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

This particular snippet helps me create Datamapper ORM models on the fly. When I type `dmm` the Snippet is fired and my cursor is placed in two areas at the same time; the class's name & the assignment to `$table`. The first cursor requires capitalization whereas the second cursor should not. Can I force the Snippet's case? Something like `{1.toLowerCase}`

Simple example, but I can think of other times when I could use this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [substitution](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) and the [Perl format string syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html)

I have tested this code:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<?php
class ${1} extends Datamapper
{
    var \$has_one = array();
    var \$has_many = array();
    var \$table = '${1/(.+)/\L\1/g}s';
    //constructor and other stuff next...
}
?>
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>dmm</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Regards,
Armando

Comment: I'm trying to use this code but it crashes ST... is that all there is to it? copying and pasting should work?

Comment: Hi @Pier. I have tested it with the latest version of Sublime Text 2 ([build 2200](http://www.sublimetext.com/dev)) creating a new snippet (Tools > New Snippet...) and storing it in the default folder (Packages/User)